# Why do prosodic marks in babel-latin package cause some words to go past textwidth?

Tags: babel, geometry, latin

I am trying to copy a book in written in Latin using `babel-latin` package in Classic Latin variant. This package provides shorthands for prosodic marks if one loads the language with the `withprosodicmarks` modifier. Example (from the documentation):

[image]

However, I have noticed that sometimes when a line ends with a word that contains such mark, it spills into the margins. Here is an example from my document:

[image]

[image]

I am confident that it has something to do with `babel-latin` because when I do not use the environment for prosodic mark, this error disappears. Below, I will provide a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Encoding, fonts, and languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, classiclatin.withprosodicmarks]{babel}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Page dimensions and margins
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    inner=0.75in,
    outer=2in
]{geometry}

% Show margins
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{IMPERIVM ROMANVM}

\ProsodicMarksOn

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

\ProsodicMarksOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's hard to test as you have provided no example, but probably the marks are using constructed acecnt commands rather than characters in T1 encoding, so that would inhibit hyphenation. You may to better in luatex using TU (Unicode) encoded fonts or add hyphnation points explicitly with `\-`

Comment: For an example you can probably omit most of the code you have shown, as you probably don't need the font and definititely don't need lettrine, but we do need a small self contained example that  linebreaks badly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added MWE. Thank you for your comments and let me know if you are able to solve this using pdflatex. Also, if I can help in any way, I'm here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed the MWE. Now, it contains even less packages. It turns out that even when one takes out the lettrine and GoudyIn package that were used to obtain that letter R in the first paragraph, the issue persists.

Comment: yes sure they were unlikely to be related. Thanks for making the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accents are not all in T1 encoding, so just like using OT1 ecoding for modern European languages, an `\accent` construct gets used which inhibits hyphenation.

You could specify hyphenation where needed using `\-`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Encoding, fonts, and languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, classiclatin.withprosodicmarks]{babel}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Page dimensions and margins
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    inner=0.75in,
    outer=2in
]{geometry}

% Show margins
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{IMPERIVM ROMANVM}

\ProsodicMarksOn


Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=e\-nus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anu\-vius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

\ProsodicMarksOff

\end{document}
```

Although to be honest I don't know if hyphnenation makes sense in classical latin?
Otherwise you could use `\sloppy` to increase the stretchability of white space

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Encoding, fonts, and languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, classiclatin.withprosodicmarks]{babel}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Page dimensions and margins
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    inner=0.75in,
    outer=2in
]{geometry}

% Show margins
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{IMPERIVM ROMANVM}

\ProsodicMarksOn
\sloppy

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

\ProsodicMarksOff

\end{document}
```

Or you could use lualatex and TU encoding that using Unicode has more pre-composed glyphs available so more hyphenation points:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Encoding, fonts, and languages
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, classiclatin.withprosodicmarks]{babel}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Page dimensions and margins
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    inner=0.75in,
    outer=2in
]{geometry}\showoutput

% Show margins
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{IMPERIVM ROMANVM}

\ProsodicMarksOn


Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

Estne N=ilus in Eur=op=a? N=ilus in Eur=op=a n=on est. Ubi est N=ilus? N=ilus
in =Afric=a est. Rh=enus ubi est? Rh=enus est in Germ=ani=a. N=ilus fluvius
est. Rh=enus fluvius est. N=ilus et Rh=enus fluvi=i sunt. D=anuvius quoque
fluvius est. Rh=enus et D=anuvius sunt fluvi=i in Germ=ani=a. Tiberis fluvius
in Itali=a est.

\ProsodicMarksOff

\end{document}
```

(actually some font warnings/substitutions in the last case but the main body is set in TU encoded garamond)